# Ruby short hand for simple if else condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there is simpler way to write this ruby code:

```
if @canonical_url
    @canonical_url
else
    request.original_url
end
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This pattern is what the or-operator is for.

```
@canonical_url || request.original_url
```

Or, in cases where the first branch isn't just the result if the test, the conditional operator works as well:

```
some_condition ? @canonical_url : request.original_url
```

Answer (score 9):

```
cond ? then_branch : else_branch
```

in your case.

```
@cononical_url ? @cononical_url : request.original_url
```

It is called a ternary.